# How to set activity no history parameter only in some cases?

Tags: java, android, themes

I have the following configuration, I have one application that is the **Main app**, and another application that is considered as a **Theme** of the first app. The second application can't function without the first one.

Now, I have to deal with two cases:

User installs the second app while he already has the first **Main app**.

User installs the second app but he does not have the first **Main app**.

1. In the first case when the users run the **second app (Theme)**, I want to redirect him to the **first app (Main)** as it's already installed. In this case I would like to remove the activity of the **second app (Theme)** from the stack. So that if users presses back, it will return him to the android desktop instead of the **second (Theme) app**. In this case the user should not be aware that there was an activity in the middle.
2. In the second case I would like to run the activity of the **second app (Theme)**. This activity has a button that redirect the user to go to google play and install the **first app (main)**. In this case if the user decides to press the back button he will go from google play, back to the activity of the **second app (Theme)**, so in this case I want the user see this activity and it's should be located in the stack as opposed to the first case.

This is my current activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Context mContext;
private RelativeLayout rlShareAndWin;
private TextView tvInPrizeTitle, tvPrizeDesc;
private boolean isCorrespondingKiboAppInstalled;
private String kiboAppPackageName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initControllers();

    initControllerListeners();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String themePackageName = getPackageName();
    kiboAppPackageName = themePackageName.substring(0, ( themePackageName.indexOf(getResources().getString(R.string.theme_away_suffix_string))));
    boolean isCorrespondingKiboAppInstalled = isKiboAppInstalledOrNot(kiboAppPackageName);
    if (isCorrespondingKiboAppInstalled) {
        Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(kiboAppPackageName);
        //launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}

private void initControllers() {
    mContext = this;
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Helvetica LT 97 Black Condensed Oblique_0.ttf");

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity_main);

    rlShareAndWin = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlShareAndWin);
    tvInPrizeTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInPrizeTitle);
    tvPrizeDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrizeDesc);

    tvInPrizeTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
    tvPrizeDesc.setTypeface(typeface);
}

private void initControllerListeners() {
    rlShareAndWin.setOnClickListener(OnClickShareAndWin);
}

private View.OnClickListener OnClickShareAndWin = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        goToPlayStoreToInstallKiboApp(kiboAppPackageName);
    }
};

private void goToPlayStoreToInstallKiboApp(String aKiboAppPackageName) {
    launchGooglePlayWithPackage(mContext, aKiboAppPackageName);
}

public void launchGooglePlayWithPackage(Context aContext, String packageName) {
    try {
        aContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        aContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
    }
}

private boolean isKiboAppInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean appInstalled = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        appInstalled = true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        appInstalled = false;
    }
    return appInstalled ;
}
}
```

You can see that I tried to set:

`launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`,

```
launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

To the intent that starts the main app in case it's installed. but non of those helps me to achieve what I want.

Comment: Even I am wondering, calling finish while you start app A from app B in first case doesn't work?

Comment: It's works, for some reason at my first try I got some unexpected behavior..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `finish()` after doing `startActivity()` to remove previous activity from the stack.

Like so:

```
 if (isCorrespondingKiboAppInstalled) {
        Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(kiboAppPackageName);
        startActivity(launchIntent);
        finish();
    }
```